# How to fix drop down menu? All choices show ">"

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

Here is my code for my drop down menu. On one server, the appropriate numbers are shown. But on another, I am seeing ">" for each choice in the drop down menu. I'm guessing this has something to do with the php.ini file, but I'm not sure...

```
<?php
// connect to the database
require 'connect.php';

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Drop Down Menu to choose Start and End dates
$startyear = ""; 
$startmonth = "";
$startday = "";
$endyear = "";
$endmonth = "";
$endday = "";

// Array of values for form
$year  = range(1998,2012);
$month = range(01,12);
$day   = range(01,31);

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
{
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
    {
        if(is_numeric($value))
        {
            $$key = $value;
        }
    }
}

?>

<form name='update' action='' method='POST'>
Start: <select name='startyear'>
    <?php foreach(array_reverse($year) as $y):?>
    <option value="<?=$y?>"<?=((isset($startyear) && $startyear == $y)?' selected':null)?>><?=$y?></option>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
<select name='startmonth'>
    <?php foreach($month as $m): $m = str_pad($m, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);?>
    <option value="<?=$m;?>"<?=((isset($startmonth) && $startmonth == $m)?' selected':null)?>><?=$m;?></option>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
    <select name='startday'>
    <?php foreach($day as $d): $d = str_pad($d, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);?>
    <option value="<?=$d;?>"<?=((isset($startday) && $startday == $d)?' selected':null)?>><?=$d;?></option>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
<br>
End: <select name='endyear'>
    <?php foreach(array_reverse($year) as $y):?>
    <option value="<?=$y?>"<?=((isset($endyear) && $endyear == $y)?' selected':null)?>><?=$y?></option>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
<select name='endmonth'>
    <?php foreach($month as $m): $m = str_pad($m, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);?>
    <option value="<?=$m;?>"<?=((isset($endmonth) && $endmonth == $m)?' selected':null)?>><?=$m;?></option>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
    <select name='endday'>
    <?php foreach($day as $d): $d = str_pad($d, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);?>
    <option value="<?=$d;?>"<?=((isset($endday) && $endday == $d)?' selected':null)?>><?=$d;?></option>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
<input type='submit' value='View'/>
</form>
```

Comment: There a reason for the down-vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try swapping the short PHP tags for the long ones.

`<?=` becomes `<?php echo`
And
`<?` becomes `<?php`

Some configurations let you use the short forms; all PHP configurations let you use the longer ones.

Comment: You're welcome. It's generally always worth using the longer form PHP tags, as it makes your code more portable.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
selected':null)?>><?=$y?></option>
```

to

```
selected':null)?><?=$y?></option>
```

There are too many `>`